# Why does location matching change when using proxy_pass in nginx?

Tags: nginx

### Simple nginx config

```
server {
  listen 0.0.0.0:80;

  server_name localhost 127.0.0.1;

  location /en-us/ {
    return 301 http://www.lego.com;
  }
}
```

Here's what happens when I `curl` that config without a trailing slash on `/en-us`.

```
curl -v http://127.0.0.1/en-us -o /dev/null
# HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

I expect that 404. The `location` block is using a [prefix match](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms), and so it makes sense to me that `/en-us` is not matching that block.

*Here's where I get confused...*

### Same config, but with a proxy_pass

Here I use the same config, but instead of returning a 301 I do a `proxy_pass`.

```
server {
  listen 0.0.0.0:80;

  server_name localhost 127.0.0.1;

  location /en-us/ {
    proxy_pass http://www.lego.com;
  }
}
```

Now watch what happens when I run the same `curl`.

```
curl -v http://127.0.0.1/en-us -o /dev/null
# HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
```

That 301 on `/en-us` makes no sense to me. It's redirecting to `Location: http://127.0.0.1/en-us/`.

In the first config, `/en-us` seemed to *not* match my `location` block (404). In the second config, `/en-us` *did* (301).

1. Why do the same location rules seem to match differently between my two configs?
2. Why would that second config result in a 301 to add a trailing slash?

I'm using `nginx version: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)`

Comment: http://nginx.org/r/location read last paragraph

Comment: That explains it perfectly. Thank you! "If a location is defined by a prefix string that ends with the slash character, and requests are processed by one of proxy_pass, fastcgi_pass, ... then the special processing is performed ... a permanent redirect with the code 301 will be returned to the requested URI with the slash appended ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) explains things clearly, as is pointed out in the comments.

> If a location is defined by a prefix string that ends with the slash character, and requests are processed by one of proxy_pass, fastcgi_pass, ... then the special processing is performed ... a permanent redirect with the code 301 will be returned to the requested URI with the slash appended ...

Special processing is done for trailing slashes on a `proxy_pass`